# Best algorithm to use to predict end time for sports program

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, statistics

say for example i know than an nba game is scheduled at 9:00 AM to 11:00 AM and that near the end it goes to overtime. id like to predict what time it actually ends by parsing twitter for predictions.  say the data i receive from twitter for predicted game  end timeare:

11:05 am,
11:07 am,
11:25 am,
10:45 am,
13:05 am,
11:15 am,
11:27 am,
...

what algorithm will best produce the correct answer? all i can think of is just averaging the parsed data. i'm trying to understand other machine learning algorithms but it seems they are too much for what i'm trying to achieve here. if it's not, can you suggest the best algorithm to use for this?

Comment: Do you want to make a single prediction or a series of predictions as you get fresher information ?

Comment: id like a series of prediction based on fresher information

Comment: Can you show a plot of the predictions received as a function of the reception time ? This is to see if how is the trend.

Comment: sorry, just got my net back. say there is a trend in the data can i use naive Bayes to predict the end time by giving more weight to the latest received data?

Comment: also, here is the plot of the sample data in r, imgur.com/gallery/E0RRvNQ/new, the Y-axis is the predicted end time, the X-axis is the time it was parsed in twitter

Comment: Given the regularity, these figures must be produced automatically. I assume that the X and Y scales differ (please confirm). How many games are there on the plot (can you color them) ? Do the traces stop at the true end ?

Comment: the X-axis is the time it was parsed from twitter, the Y-axis is the predicted end time tweeted. The graph is just an example I created using R.. All the parsed data in the example graph is only for a certain one game.  What do you mean traces stop at the true end? The example graph shows all the data that was received from tweeter.

Comment: can i use naive Bayes here to get the highest probability end time for the game?

Comment: I'd prefer to see true data. The plot doesn't show ground truth so it is impossible to see how good the predictions are.

Comment: I still haven't scraped for real data, still working on hypothetical here. But say they were the real data, can naive Bayes be applied here? sorry if this sounds stupid, i'm still trying to process all the machine learning algorithms i find on the net.

Comment: If you have no data to show then my random answer is "yes, you can".

Comment: well i guess, you are right, it's too hypothetical to yield a specific answer. thank you so much for answering though. the questions you asked me were very helpful and got me thinking. again, thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things you can consider to add to you method :

- If you have the timestamp of each prediction, use weighted average with a bigger weight on the more recent predictions, as they are more likely to be accurate.
- If you assume a Normal distribution, you can try to remove the outliers, i.e values outside  [-3 sigma, +3 sigma]
- If each prediction contains metadata such as the author, you can weight the prediction according to the accuracy of previous prediction of this author.

I hope this can help

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure machine learning algorithms will help you if the only data you have is the predictions you parse from predictions on Twitter. You'd need to know the length of previous games and have a set of attributes regarding those past games. That way your learning algorithm could learn from the games which you already know the length of.